# Excel Addin rejected due to Mac

Tags: office-store

I can test my addin in Excel for Windows / Online, but can't test it from a Mac and iPad because I don't have that setup and don't have plans to acquire it.
I'm being rejected because of Mac tests by the team, and I'm unable to fix the errors.

Is there any way to cap Macs from the manifest file and don't make them avaible to Mac users when they browse the store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Office Web Add-ins are designed to work across the entire Office platform. As such, there isn't a mechanism for enabling the add-in by platform.

In the end, these add-ins are just web apps that run within a browser context. If you're running into a blocker on a single platform, posting those questions on Stack Overflow would be a reasonable next-step. Generally browser specific issues are well known by the community here and can be quickly answered.

There are also several vendors that offer cloud-based Mac access. [MacinCloud](https://portal.macincloud.com/select/#/plans) for example has a $1 per hour option (you pre-pay for 30 hours so it's a $30 investment). I've used this service myself for testing add-ins.

Comment: I'll take your suggestion and use this cloud-based service. Thanks!